# ASP.NET Timers don't work in Metro Windows 8 IE 10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-8, timer

This problem is related to the Metro Mode of the IE10 browser in Windows 8.

I created a website using ASP.NET 4.5 and implemented some timers in it using the Timer control provided in ASP.NET. Now the Timers are supposed to work even when someone has opened a new tab and are working on that tab or have opened a new application and are working on that new application.

For Example:- 
Let say someone opened my website and the timers are now ticking, now if I open a new tab or if I open a new program like MS Word, Notepad or any other application then the Timers should keep on working in the background.

Now this works fine in IE 10 but only in the Desktop Mode, but if I open the website in the Metro Mode of the IE10 browser and then if I open a new tab or switch to some other application the Timers Pause i.e. they stop ticking and only resume their Ticking when I come back to the tab in which the website is opened.

So can anyone please tell me how can I make the ASP.NET Timers tick in the background while in Metro Mode of IE10 browser.

Also I read somewhere that IE10 Metro Mode doesn't support most of the features found in IE10 Desktop Mode and that IE10 Metro Mode was made for touch screens, so is this the problem?

I also tried the same thing with Google Chrome browser, I tested the website in the Desktop Mode and then again tested the website in Windows 8 Mode and both the time the ASP.NET timers worked the way they should while I was working on a new tab or on some other application.

So this problem is only there in the IE10 Metro Mode.

I am using the normal classic ASP.NET 4.5 and not MVC or Razor or any other framework.

OR if there is no solution then is there a way to automatically switch the user from the IE10 Metro Mode to the IE10 Desktop Mode?

Answer (score 1):

To automatically switch the user from the IE10 Metro Mode to the IE10 Desktop Mode, you can use this document:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557(v=vs.85).aspx

I understand that only need put this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true"/>
```